# How to Refresh mlab scene on camera change using callbacks

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using Mayavi2 module of Python to create a 3D mesh. I also want to show the projection of the mesh onto a surface each time the mesh is rotated. I found out that one can use callbacks for that purpose. http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_volume_slicer.html

But I couldn't find out which callback will work for my purpose. I am quite new to Mayavi, and maybe the answer is very obvious but so far it's eluding me. I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, I've discovered that the callback "@on_trait_change('<scene_name>.busy')" works. It's not perfect, because it sometimes triggers the attached functions even though camera has not been rotated. That can be taken care of by storing the camera variables and checking for change in the callback function.